# wordpress footer moves to the top of main content when using custom pages

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, program-entry-point

I've just started using wordpress for CMS and I've built a test website - however on the pages when I've added a custom page template the footer moves up to the very top of the main content area. I've tried searching the web and used some fixes mentioned in tutorials clear: both; etc.. and nothing has corrected the problem . Any help to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

the static home page is working fine: 
http://creative-media.info/wp/

however on the following custom page below - you'll be able to see the footer error.
http://creative-media.info/wp/gallery-lightbox/

kind regards

Paul

Comment: Just  copy the  page.php  format and try to use that  for custom page there is missing  of some unclosed div

Comment: Hi vicky the custom pages are based on working code from the page.php that's why I can't understand why the footer rises to the top on these pages only? any help would be greatly appreciated. cheers paul

Comment: remove and  back up   the content from back end for the page  and adjust  the footer  there may be  some enclosed div  in data

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be `<div id="whiteboxfaz">  </div>`

Remove in that id `position: absolute;`

Comment: Your problematic webpage seems to be fixed now. If this answer helped you with that, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox located on the left side of this answer.